# Conversion to Dalvik error 1 No SOlution Worked

Tags: android, eclipse, dalvik

i'm running on eclipse luna with adt and all is fine until i add google play service as a library 
the application wont run or debug and the eclipse goes to sleep for a long time
trying to export signed apk it throws me     Conversion to Dalvik error 1
that is the error log

```
eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700
java.version=1.8.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product         
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

com.android.ide.eclipse.adt
Error
Fri Aug 07 01:40:57 EET 2015
Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexException: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:792)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(ExportHelper.java:274)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.doExport(ExportWizard.java:313)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.access$0(ExportWizard.java:238)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard$1.run(ExportWizard.java:223)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
```

Any Help Apreciated, i got bored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by updating to eclipse mars

Comment: I have the same problem and turn around for the last 3 days... I will try this